# HiQPdf - Images missing in pdf

Tags: c#, hiqpdf

I want to convert an html string to pdf with images located at a specific location. I have the html code loaded into a string.  I have the images that go with the html located in c:\temp\ .  I can get this to work if I save the html string to a file as seen in the example below.  I really dont need to write the html to a file.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I'm using the 3rd party component HiQPDF and I have already contacted them.

```
    private void ConvertToPDF(string htmlbody, string pdfname)
    {
        HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
        // set a demo serial number
        htmlToPdfConverter.SerialNumber = "-- HiQPdf Serial Number --";
        htmlToPdfConverter.Document.Margins = new PdfMargins(5);

        //doesnt work
        htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToFile(htmlbody, @"c:\temp\", pdfname);
        //works just fine :-( , but it forces me to save to the disk
        htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToFile(@"C:\temp\1Z7039680342477761-00a26b62-f6d3-47e3-92c3-18b907665aaa.html", pdfname);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Nick you have just made your serial number public... please regenerate it as soon as possible so that the one you posted doesn't work. Even if the question is edited, the sensitive data is present on the history. I've already flagged your question so that a moderator can remove it from the history. But next time, be sure **not to include** sensitive data on your questions

Comment: that was actually the demo serial number that everyone gets.

Answer (score 1):

Set the base URL as file:///C:\temp/ instead of "c:\temp".  This information comes directly from hiqpdf support.